# Adding option to a select with jQuery messes with the text indexes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm making a screen for users to verify documents, using certain objects and localStorage to save what the user has done in case he accidentally closes the browser or something among those lines. Due the documents being of different cattegories I don't display all of them at once, instead I empty the select of options and add them dinamically. When the user returns to a different filter, I check the local storage and mark the options the user has already verified. For example: instead of showing "Document 1" the option text must say "Document 1 -- Verified --".

However, I've found that adding options dinamically messes with the text indexes. It displays them correctly to the browser, but when trying to access to them, I found that all the text was added to the element 0, instead of adding to the element 1,2... and so on. So it becomes harder for me to add the "--Verified--" at the tags, I'd need to add something to differentiate the lines, then split them and add the "--Verified--"

Here is a simple example code to show the issue. I wrote this specially to show the problem

```
<select id="Documents">
<option val="-1">--Select a document--</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button id="button">Click to add an option</button>
```

Sample JavaScript + jQuery:

```
var i = 0;

$("#button").on("click", addOption);

function addOption() {
var text="New option added";
$("#Documents").append(new Option(text, i));
++i;
alert($("#Documents").eq(0).text());
alert($("#Documents").eq(i).text());
}
```

When the call to the .eq(0).text() is done, the alert shows "--Select a documentNew option added". Meanwhile, eq(i).text() will return "", and a call to .eq(i).val() returns undefined. Am I doing something wrong?

A fiddle with the code if you want to check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ek563nd7/1/

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `eq()` is wrong here, basically you are trying to select the element with id `Documents` with index `i`, but what you want is the children (the `options`) of `select#Documents`, right?

so, I believe you want to use:
`$("#Documents").children().eq(i).text()`

See below snippet

```js
var i = 0;

$("#button").on("click", addOption);

function addOption() {
  var text = "New option added_" + i;
  $("#Documents").append(new Option(text, i));
  ++i;
  console.log($("#Documents").children().eq(i).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Documents">
  <option val="-1">--Select a document--</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button id="button">Click to add an option</button>
```

the [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) is used to *Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.*, So, you were trying to reduce the matched elements with id `Documents`, that is only one, the `<select>`.

Comment: wow dude, you are right. Just to think I spent a couple of hours with this... I've checked the jQuery docs and it says that .eq() reduces the set of matches to the specified index. May I ask why using .eq(0) showed the thext of all? I was thinking it must return an undefined, since the select tag had no text attribute

Comment: actually, it has a `text`, since, the docs say: *"Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, **including their descendants**"* So, `#Documents` has text in its descendants